# String width change

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Tableau report where the width of a field is 2 as it is a state abbreviation. It turns out that I need to include a value of "Unknown" for the state if it was null in the data. The report pulls from a view and I've updated the view so the state column is now varchar(7) and contains values of "Unknown". I've tried every trick I can think of to convince Tableau that the state field is now 7 characters wide and it refuses to recognize the change. How can I force the data change to 7 characters?

Comment: Are you saying that the value "Unknown" is being truncated in Tableau? Tableau has no internal string length limit. You should have refreshed your data connection, too.

Comment: Yes. If I ask Tableau to describe the state field it says it is 2 characters.
I've tried taking the view out and putting it back in. I don't know how to refresh it any better than that.

Comment: Does the data get truncated, though? When you display it, does it only show "Un" instead of "Unknown"??

Comment: Yes, the data gets truncated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you connecting to? SQL Server, MySQL, etc?

Comment: (1) When you query your view directly (eg. in SSMS) is "Unknown" truncated?   (2) If you connect to that same view using a new Tableau workbook, do you have the same issue?